# There is an equivalent of login.sql on PostgresSQL?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, sqlplus, psql

When you log on Oracle database with SQLplus, it looks for a login.sql file in the current directory. If the file exists, it's executed.

It's usefull to set preferences...

There is an equivalent when I log to a PostgreSQL database with psql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's stored in `~/.psqlrc`

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN85369